# Filled Point in OpenStreetMap

Tags: php, html, openlayers, openstreetmap

I would like to show a filled point (red colour) in a OSM from PHP. I have tried numerous changes unsuccessfully. With my code, I have only got a transparent point in an specific location.

```
<?php

echo '
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>

<script>

var attribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
    collapsible: true
});
    
    var map = new ol.Map({
        controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution: false}).extend([attribution]),
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM({
                    maxZoom: 18
                })
            })
            ],
            target: "map",
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-4.561,37.019]),
                maxZoom: 18,
                zoom: 10
            })
    });
 

        var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [
                    new ol.Feature({
';

echo "
                        geometry: new ol.geom.Circle(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-4.561,37.019]),9000,'XY')})
                    ]
            })
        });



            map.addLayer(layer);

           
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>";

?>
```

I expect to show a filled point in a specific location on a OS Map

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Point geometry and a style with a red fill

```
    var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [
                new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-4.561,37.019]))})
                ]
        }),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 5,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: "red"  
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

`radius` is in pixels and can be changed to suit your requirements

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it is working perfectly. The thing is I have a model with information in order to be shown on the map. I got it but if I separate the code using a function, it doesnt work. My code, including the function is: